# Change navbar background on scroll

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to change the color of my navbar from transparent to 'bg-red-50' when I start scrolling. Following is my approach to this issue. The background is transparent and isn't changing on scroll. Moreover, nothing is being logged to console suggesting that `handleScroll` function isn't being called at all.

```js
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const NavLayout = ({ layout, children }) => {
    const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            if (window.scrollY > 0) {
                setScrolling(true);
            } else {
                setScrolling(false);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []); 

    return (
        <nav
            className={`${layout} absolute top-3 left-3 w-[98%] rounded py-2 px-10 text-xl ${
                scrolling ? "bg-red-50" : ""
            } z-50 h-[70px]`}
        >
            {children}
        </nav>
    );
};

export default NavLayout;
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Working as expected , not reproducible https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-gkng4j?file=app%2FNavBar.tsx

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have imported and used the 'NavLayout' component correctly in your application,then make sure that you are using a browser that supports the scroll event and if there are any other event listeners on the window object that might conflict with your scroll event listener.